# Hive : FAILED: SemanticException Column Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run a query as follows

```
hive -e "set hive.execution.engine=mr;set hive.strict.checks.cartesian.product=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;use db1; select col1,col2 from tb1 where col_date='2020-08-15' and col3='Y' 
and col4='val4' and col1 not in 
( select distinct col1 from db2.tb2 where col_date='2020-08-15' and 
col5='val5' and col6='val6' and col3='Y' and col4='val4') "
```

but i keep getting

```
FAILED: SemanticException Column col1 Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries
```

what am i doing wrong ? how can i fix this ?

columns in `db1.tb1`

```
col1
col2
col_date
col3
col4
```

columns in `db2.tb2`

```
col1
col2
col_date
col3
col4
col5
col6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add aliases to tables and use them for all columns:

```
hive -e "set hive.execution.engine=mr;set hive.strict.checks.cartesian.product=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
use db1; 
select t1.col1, t1.col2 
  from tb1 t1
 where t1.col_date='2020-08-15' and t1.col3='Y' and t1.col4='val4' 
   and t1.col1 not in 
( select distinct t2.col1 from db2.tb2 t2 
   where t2.col_date='2020-08-15' and t2.col5='val5' and t2.col6='val6' and t2.col3='Y' and t2.col4='val4' ) "
```

Alternatiively, if your Hive version does not support NOT IN subquery, you can use LEFT JOIN + filter for the same

```
hive -e "set hive.execution.engine=mr;set hive.strict.checks.cartesian.product=false;
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
use db1; 
select t1.col1, t1.col2 
  from tb1 t1
       left join 
        ( select distinct t2.col1 from db2.tb2 t2 
           where t2.col_date='2020-08-15' 
             and t2.col5='val5' 
             and t2.col6='val6' 
             and t2.col3='Y' 
             and t2.col4='val4' 
        ) s on t1.col1 = s.col1 
 where t1.col_date='2020-08-15' and t1.col3='Y' and t1.col4='val4' 
   and s.col1 is null --filter out joined records
"
```